# Shopify App/Nextjs: How to get RoutePropagator to work?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, shopify, shopify-app

How do I get route propagation working in a Nextjs Shopify app?

I'm building a Shopify App scaffolded with the [CLI](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-node) and have issues with routing using the Nextjs router. The standard embedded app implementation does not update the URL so a RoutePropagator component is needed.

I implemented Shopify's [RoutePropagator](https://shopify.dev/apps/tools/app-bridge/react-components/route-propagator) but got the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')`

Then I found [this](https://gist.github.com/shafiimam/ab6c80c6e56ea859744bbc36dffaeee9) implementation which works for updating the URL, but runs into a really strange issue for Dynamic Urls.

Whenever a user navigated to a dynamic url, the url would update with [id] in the url. Gif example:

[image]

Narrowing it down, the below snipped causes the above dynamic url issue:

```
import { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import Router, { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { Context as AppBridgeContext } from "@shopify/app-bridge-react";
import { Redirect } from "@shopify/app-bridge/actions";
import { RoutePropagator as ShopifyRoutePropagator } from "@shopify/app-bridge-react";

const RoutePropagator = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { route } = router;
  const appBridge = React.useContext(AppBridgeContext);

  // Subscribe to appBridge changes - captures appBridge urls
  // and sends them to Next.js router. Use useEffect hook to
  // load once when component mounted
  useEffect(() => {
    appBridge.subscribe(Redirect.Action.APP, ({ path }) => {
      Router.push(path);
    });
  }, []);

  return appBridge && route ? (
    <ShopifyRoutePropagator location={route} app={appBridge} />
  ) : null;
};

export default RoutePropagator;
```

How do I get the URL to update as the user navigates through the application for all urls (including dynamic urls)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
const { asPath } = router
```

instead of `route` and it's gonna work!